# two tables not equal

Tags: php

I have a SQL query and here it is the part I'm stuck on.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid FROM user, staff WHERE user.type = 'Staff' AND staff.userid!= user.userid";
```

For some reason, it only prints out the part where users are staff but the != is not working, where as if I remove the ! and only have staff.user_id = user.user_id it works and prints out all users that are in both of those tables?

Can someone please explain why is this is happen and have a solution.

EDIT

```
TABLE USER                       TABLE STAFF
ID - NAME - TYPE                ID   -     NUMBER
1  - A    - Staff               1    -      11111
2  - B    - Staff               2    -      22222
3  - C    - Customer
4  - D    - Customer
5  - E    - Staff
6  - F    - Staff
```

How would I find the users id 5 and 6?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @Will Ok, I edited my answer to reflect the modified question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `<>` instead of `!=`.

Edited answer for the edited question:

```
SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid 
FROM user LEFT JOIN staff ON user.userid=staff.userid 
WHERE user.type = 'Staff' AND staff.userid IS NULL ;
```

Comment: I agree, <> is the formal syntax, most SQL databases support != because it's common coder lingo but it's not the official syntax for not equals.

Comment: @Will What is the desired output you want?

Comment: @Will Do you want the `user` tagged with `type='Staff'` that are NOT listed in the staff table?

Answer (score 4):

OK, based on your comment, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN staff s ON (s.userid = u.userid)  
WHERE (s.userid is null) AND (u.type = 'Staff')
```

The left join will find all the records in user table (the left table) that have a matching userid and for those that don't.

So a modified query

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN staff s ON (s.userid = u.userid)
```

would return

```
 
1  - A    - Staff               1    -      11111
2  - B    - Staff               2    -      22222
3  - C    - Customer            NULL NULL NULL
4  - D    - Customer            NULL NULL NULL
5  - E    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
6  - F    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
```

adding a partial WHERE clause

```
SELECT *
    FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN staff s ON (s.userid = u.userid)  
    WHERE (s.userid is null)
```

would return:

```
 
3  - C    - Customer            NULL NULL NULL
4  - D    - Customer            NULL NULL NULL
5  - E    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
6  - F    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
```

And finally the complete query would return

```
SELECT *
    FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN staff s ON (s.userid = u.userid)  
    WHERE (s.userid is null) AND (u.type = 'Staff')
```

would return:

```
 
5  - E    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
6  - F    - Staff               NULL NULL NULL
```

Note: assuming the user table is unique, the 'DISTINCT' is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You are joining two tables (user and staff) and using a join condition where the user type is staff and the userids between the user and staff table do not match.

using the JOIN syntax you are saying

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid 
FROM user u
JOIN staff s ON (s.userid != u.userid)  
WHERE u.type = 'Staff'
```

But you aren't using anything from the Staff table in your select. So I'm unclear on the need to join to it in the first place?

Comment: I have user table with user details, id and the type field will either be staff or customers. The staff table will have the id and the staff number. What I want to do is have a list of all staff that are not in the staff table? With the user.userid = staff.userid, will print all the staff that are in the staff and user table, but I want the staff that are not in the staff table from the user table. If you know what I mean

Comment: Sorry I explain best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid FROM user,staff 
WHERE user.userid=staff.userid  and user.type = 'Staff' AND staff.userid IS NULL;
```